# Erro para usar filtro mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

estou com um erro ao tentar executar um filtro no banco de dados.

```
var params = '{"cd_entidade":"'+ vcd_entidade+'"}';

Movmaterial.find(params).toArray(function(err,docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);
}
```

ocorreu um erro que nao estou conseguindo resolver, já tem dois dias :(
poderiam me ajudar? estou criando um projeto pessoal para estudos do uso do mongodb, desde já agradeço

Comment: Qual é o erro que te está a dar?

Comment: find(...).toArray is not a function at Object.index

Comment: `Movmaterial` é a tua mongodb? O retorno provavelmente não é válido para não conseguires chamar o `toArray`, faz debug ao que o `find` retorna. Ou experimenta fazer `find({}).toArray`.

Comment: obrigado pelo interesse, vamos lá..

Comment: Movmaterial é mongodb e funciona quando eu faço da seguinte forma: Movmaterial.find({cd_entidade:vcd_entidade},function(err,docs){.. quando coloco dentro de uma variavel nao funciona. este é apenas um exemplo, pois vou incluir mais argumentos para filtrar melhor os dados.

Comment: Já tentei colocar da forma sugerida e o erro que gerou foi: TypeError: Movmaterial.find(...).toArray is not a function at Object.index

Comment: desta forma que enviei agora, nao gerou erro, selecionou todos os dados da collection. o problema é que nao filtrou os dados, processou todos os documentos no console.log.

Answer (score 0):

O teu `params` é uma string, usa um objecto de javascript normal.

```
// aqui nao precisas contatenar como estavas a fazer, isto será suficiente
var params = { cd_entidade: vcd_entidade };

Movmaterial.find(params).toArray(function(err,docs){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(docs);
}
```

Comment: vou tentar e retorno em seguida.

Comment: fiz conforme sugerido e retornou o mesmo erro:TypeError: Movmaterial.find(...).toArray is not a function :(

Comment: O que retorna se usares só o `find`? `Movmaterial` é a `collection` ou uma `db`?

Comment: eu estou usando como collection. na definição inicial do arquivo e crio uma variavel:  var Movmaterial     = app.models.movmaterial;

Comment: onde o movmaterial é a collection. na pasta model segue a definição da model: module.exports = function() {
 var movmaterialSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  data_entrada : {type: Date, default: Date},
  cd_entidade  : {type: String, trim: true},
  cd_nro_nf  : {type: String, trim: true},
  id_ativo  : {type: String, trim: true},
  ds_ativmaterial : {type: String, trim: true}
 });
 return mongoose.model('Movmaterial', movmaterialSchema);
}

Comment: E só o `find`? Porque o `.toArray` nao consegue ser chamado devido ao retorno do `find`

Comment: eu tentei desta forma: Movmaterial.find(params,function(err,docs){..... retornou os dados mas nao aplicou o filtro, gerou todos os dados da collection.

Comment: não gerou erro, mas nao filtrou os dados. veja como ficou. var params = { cd_entidade: vcd_entidade }

    Movmaterial.find(params,function(err,docs){
     if (err){
      req.flash('erro','Erro : '+err);
      docs = [];
      res.render('movmaterial/index',{lista: docs,cd_entidade:req.params.cd_entidade,entidade:dbent,material:dbtmat});      
     }else {
     console.log(docs);
     res.render('movmaterial/index',{lista: docs,cd_entidade:req.params.cd_entidade,entidade:dbent,material:dbtmat});
     }
    });

Comment: as informações do filtro, se aplicadas não selecionaria dados para listar, a informação no filtro nao existe, tenho a impressão que o filtro nao foi considerado como argumento para filtrar no banco de dados.

Comment: Consgui reoslver....:)

Comment: consegui resolver o problema

Comment: não precisei usar o toArray, conforme você informou @Leite.  funcionou:             
var params = Object({ cd_entidade: vcd_entidade});
console.log(params)
Movmaterial.find(params,function(err,docs){
if (err){
 req.flash('erro','Erro : '+err);
 docs = [];
 res.render('movmaterial/index',{lista: docs});      
}else {
 console.log(docs);
 res.render('movmaterial/index',{lista: docs});
}
});

Comment: defini o param da seguinte forma: var params = Object({ cd_entidade: vcd_entidade}); onde o vcd_entidade é uma var que será incluído os argumentos para filtragem. Grato pela Ajuda e pelas dicas, me ajudaram muito. Grato.